zfs drive (not root) not automounting on boot
I run ubuntu 24.04 and formatted a drive with zfs and it works as expected. But it is not mounted automatically on bootup. Sometimes it does and sometimes not. If i boot up another distro och boot back into ubuntu the drives is not automounting. Every reboot i usually have to run:
sudo zpool import 'mypoolname'
I have searched a solution but all i have understood is that zfs drives should automount without any settings.
I have tried to add a cronjob with "sudo zpool import 'mypoolname'" but that doesnt work.
Updated solution:
Adding a cronjob fixed it but it need to be set correctly. i did this as following(with some guide somewhere) after i ran chronjob as described here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804
crontab -e
Added the following to the end of the file. (It just waits 10 seconds and then imports all zpools)
@reboot sleep 10 sudo zpool import -a

Tried to make a cronjob to run at boot and ran:
crontab -e

Then I added the following line to the end of the file and saved it.
@reboot sleep 10 sudo zpool import -a

But no, it didn't work. Guess my cronjob skills need improving. I wish there was something simple like fstab to add importing the pools into. It is kind of weird as an USB drive I formatted in ZFS and intermittently turn of and on and that one mount/import like expected.
So I ran
sudo systemctl status cron.service

and cron.service is running...
I need to learn how cronjobs work as it doesnt work what i have done.
